# How can I edit a web part's .css file on the fly in MOSS 2007?

Tags: css, sharepoint, moss, wss, web-parts

I have a web part that is installed using a feature. This web part has a css file that is deployed and I need to tweak it, but can't find it anywhere. I suspect it might be in the SQL Server DB. 
So how can I find it, edit it and see changes on the fly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to trace where the .CSS file is located, you have a coupl of options.
You can use the IE [developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en). If you have Internet Explore version 8, you already have it.

Press F12 to open the tool bar. Press CTRL+B and use the mouse to locate and find the element you are interested in.

Select the CSS tab in the left toolbar and locate the CSS file in the dropdown box, or the "Trace styles" on the right hand side and see which CSS file is the base for the style.

The IE developer tool bar also lets you change CSS parameters on the fly so you can see how the result will be directly when you edit them.

Comment: Thanks! The file has been residing in "C:\PROGRAM FILES\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT SHARED\WEB SERVER EXTENSIONS\WPRESOURCES\

Comment: Great. But you must understand that the best way is to edit the actual feature/solution package instead, because if you edit the file, it will be overwritten when the feature is uninstalled/re-installed.

Comment: Yes sure I understand that! But I want to see changes immediately for incremental development. Later I'll put the css into the solution package.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript will allow you to change styles and CSS on the fly. AFIK this is the only way to do it at runtime.  I would recommend using a lib like JQuery to make it less painful and to leverage existing code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I really meant a bit different task. I'll try to phrase the question better next time)